# How to convert two vectors to three Euler angles

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

I am trying to convert two vectors to Three Euler angles. My goal is to be able to type this formula in excel and be able to convert them to Euler angles.

The first angle is "β" Which rotates around the X axis. The Second angle is "ϕ" which rotates around the Y axis.  The Third angle is "α" which rotates around the Z axis.

The Two vectors as an example would look like this `BX0 BY-1 BZ0 NX-1 NY0 NZ0`. The first B Vector is the directional vector or right vector which points in the X Direction. The N Vector is the Forward Vector which points in the Z Direction.

So far I have:

```
α= ARCTAN(NX/NY)

β= ARCTAN((SQRT(NX^2+NY^2))/NZ)
```

These work only if N vector are not `0` in which some cases they are as in the example above.

Comment: See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms) for formulas for converting, for instance, from a rotation matrix to Euler angles

Comment: Thanks for the link but I dont quite understand how to make a rotation matrix from the vectors I have to apply the formulas.  I know the Euler Angle Sequence is XYZ.  Do you have an example using the info above and on the link?

Answer (score 2):

You have a vector $(B_x, B_y, B_z)$ representing the "rightward" direction
(which you are also calling the $x$ direction of the rotated system)
and a vector $(N_x, N_y, N_z)$ representing the "forward" direction
(which you are also calling the $z$ direction of the rotated system).

In order to construct a rotation matrix for the rotation, you need to compute the vector that will represent the $y$ direction in the rotated frame.
Assuming you have a right-handed coordinate system,
if $x$ points right and $z$ points forward we must have $y$ pointing downward,
so I'll call this vector $D$.

Assuming your $B$ and $N$ vectors always have length $1,$
the $D$ vector is just the cross product of the other two:

$$  D = N \times B. $$

Once you have all three vectors you simply list their coordinates in columns to make a rotation matrix:

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} B_x & D_x & N_x \\
B_y & D_y & N_y \\
B_z & D_z & N_z \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now that you have a rotation matrix, do you actually need Euler angles?
There's not much you can do with Euler angles that you can't do with a rotation matrix except to answer someone who asks you what the Euler angles are.

If you really must have Euler angles, make sure the formula you use matches the particular choice of sequence of rotation axes you want.
For example,
[this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514102/3466415)
assumes you rotate around the world $z$ axis, then the world $x$ axis, then the world $z$ axis again, whereas
[another answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37558238/3466415)
uses all three axes ($z$, then $y$, then $x$ in world coordinates,
which is equivalent to $x$, then $y$, then $z$ in body coordinates
if the body is initially aligned with the world axes).

To deal with zeros in the vectors, don't use the ordinary arctan function, use the two-variable arc tangent function, named $\operatorname{atan2}$
in many computer math libraries. For example, instead of
$\alpha = \arctan(N_x/N_y)$, write

$$  \alpha = \operatorname{atan2}(N_x, N_y). $$

For example, $\operatorname{atan2}(1, 0)$ produces the angle $\frac\pi2$ radians instead of a divide-by-zero error.
Also, $\operatorname{atan2}(-N_x, -N_y)$ will give you an angle $\pi$ radians greater or less than $\operatorname{atan2}(N_x, N_y)$, whereas
$\arctan(-N_x/-N_y) = \arctan(N_x/N_y)$ which is usually a mistake when you want the angle of a vector.

With $\operatorname{atan2}$ you only need to worry about the case where
**both** parameters are zero.
You will get double zeros only in very restricted circumstances, so handle those as special cases.